# Django Inline Formset Issue (list out of range)

Tags: django, inline-formset

This should be simple and I actually had it working yesterday. I have no idea what changed but it's now throwing an error.

```
def game_design(request):
    user=User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    organization=user.organization_set.all()[0]
    website=organization.website_set.all()[0]
    surveys=website.survey_set.all()
    error=''
    SurveyFormSet=inlineformset_factory(Website, Survey, extra=0, can_delete=True)
    NavigationFormSet=modelformset_factory(Navigation, extra=1)
    if request.method=='POST':
        survey_formset=SurveyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="surveys")
        navigation_formset=NavigationFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="navigations")
        if survey_formset.is_valid() and navigation_formset.is_valid():
                survey_formset.save()
            navigation_formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/rewards/")
        else:   
            error="Please fix your errors"
           survey_formset=SurveyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,prefix="surveys")
           navigation_formset=NavigationFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,prefix="navigations")
           return render_to_response('website/game_design.html', {'website':website,'survey_formset':survey_formset, 'navigation_formset':navigation_formset, 'error':error}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
         survey_formset=SurveyFormSet(instance=website,prefix="surveys")
         navigation_formset=NavigationFormSet(queryset=Navigation.objects.none(),prefix="navigations")
    return render_to_response("website/game_design.html", {'website':website,'survey_formset':survey_formset,'navigation_formset':navigation_formset,'error':error},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks for any help on this one

Comment: THe indentation errors here aren't present in the code.  The error appears to be thrown in the line right after I check for the POST method.  I suppose it might be a template error but I i'm using {{form.as_p}} and the existing surveys are showing up correctly

Answer (score 9):

My issue appears to have been related to not including an instance argument in my Formset.

I should have had the following:

survey_formset=SurveyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=website, prefix="surveys")

Slowly but surely I'll learn to not make stupid mistakes

Comment: Please mark as answered (this tells people viewing your question in search results etc. that it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should always post the full traceback so people can help better.

If you say nothing has changed and it was working yesterday, there's one area where code doesn't need to change to throw an `IndexError`:

```
organization=user.organization_set.all()[0]  
website=organization.website_set.all()[0]
```

You sure that's not the problem?

Either way, until we see a traceback, it's hard to tell ;)

Comment: sorry Yuji, I'm a noob. I attached the traceback.